# How do I restore use of my wallet.dat file, last used in 2013?

Tags: wallet-recovery

I found a wallet.dat file in my backup folder, which I recall last using in 2013. I'm curious to see what the BTC contents are, which I recall being a really small fraction of BTC.

In any case, is there anything preventing me from just installing Bitcoin Core and replacing the default wallet.dat to recover my backed-up wallet? What is the recommended way to recover such an old wallet.dat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In any case, is there anything preventing me from just installing Bitcoin Core and replacing the default wallet.dat to recover my backed-up wallet? What is the recommended way to recover such an old wallet.dat file?

You can do just that. In fact, that's exactly the way to restore a backup.